# cannot use BlobContainerAsyncClient to list blobs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to list blobs from container  using azure java sdk version 12.0.6. In order to getting good performance, I use async method with class `BlobContainerAsyncClient`. But I cannot list blobs with the class and I do not get any error.

My code

```
ListBlobsOptions options = new ListBlobsOptions()
            .setDetails(new BlobListDetails()
                .setRetrieveDeletedBlobs(true)
                .setRetrieveSnapshots(true));

        client.listBlobs(options).subscribe(blob ->
            System.out.printf("Name: %s, Directory? %b, Deleted? %b, Snapshot ID: %s%n",
                blob.getName(),
                blob.isPrefix(),
                blob.isDeleted(),
                blob.getSnapshot()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
ListBlobsOptions options = new ListBlobsOptions()
            .setDetails(new BlobListDetails()
                .setRetrieveDeletedBlobs(true)
                .setRetrieveSnapshots(true));
lient.listBlobs(options).doOnNext(blob ->
            System.out.printf("Name: %s, Directory? %b, Deleted? %b, Snapshot ID: %s%n",
                blob.getName(),
                blob.isPrefix(),
                blob.isDeleted(),
                blob.getSnapshot()))
             .blockLast();
```

[image]

Besides, cannot call both `subscribe()` and `block()`. When you call `subscribe()` you get back a `Disposable` which allows you to cancel the async operation, but you cannot block on this object. If you want to ensure the method in question blocks, you simply call `block()` on the operation (the type which has a `block()` method is a `Mono` or possibly a `Flux`).

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should try:

1. Use the sync APIs and ensure you get the response you expect there. If you get the results you expect, that rules out issues related to authentication, container names, and so on.
2. Because your code above is async, you need to be sure that the application is not exiting before the response is received from the service. If you could update your code listing above to show more fully what you're doing, we can rule that out. For the sake of increasing confidence, you may also choose to do one of the two things to temporarily increase confidence that your async code is correct:

   1. Temporarily add a `Thread.sleep(5000)` call after your subscribe call.
   2. Replace the `.subscribe()` call with a `.block()` call, essentially turning the request back into a sync call.

Comment: I cannot add `block` method after the `subscribe` method.